# EVGA GTX 970 with Antergos

Tags: drivers, nvidia, antergos

I've had troubles trying to install Antergos with my EVGA GTX 970. I asked on their forums and the only person that replied, thought I was using a laptop, but I'm using a custom built desktop. I've installed Antergos successfully but every time I boot I have to manually add the flag nouveau.modeset=0 which makes every thing on the screen lag.

[I found a topic on this](https://forum.antergos.com/topic/2302/booting-from-usb-results-in-black-screen-gtx-970/2), but it was from last year and the commands that was given ended up breaking my installation of it and I had to reinstall Antergos.

So I was wondering what the commands were for installing the latest Nvidia drivers on Arch or Antergos that support a dedicated EVGA GTX 970. Thanks!

Comment: Could you [edit] into your post a link to the topic you found that broke your installation? Pardon my confusion.

Comment: My Nvidia 970 works fine on Arch.  The only packages I needed to install were `nvidia` and `nvidia-libgl`.  Do you have these packages installed? Make sure you do *not* have `mesa-libgl` installed as well.

Comment: @ElderGeek I did so now. jayhendren I'll try that now, thanks.

Comment: @jayhendren this worked and was a lot more simple than the other solutions I was reading. Go ahead and make it an actual answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Ok I'll add that as an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the packages `nvidia` and `nvidia-libgl` installed from the official repos.  Additionally, `mesa-libgl` does not work well with either of these packages, so make sure this package is not installed.

Comment: Just wanted to add, as I installed `nvidia-libgl` it prompted me that it conflicted with `mesa-libgl` and gave me a choice to remove it.